# Sorting issue when using combobox with item and keeping itemdata in sortedlist type

Tags: c#, .net, sorting, combobox, sortedlist

I have a project that keeping items and itemdata(number) with a sorted why.
I have 2 objects:
1.sorted Combobox that keeps the items(names)
2.sortedlist that keeps the item(name) as key and itemdata(number) as value.

For some reason some character(for example "-") is not sorted the same way in the combo and in the sortedlist.the combo keeping the string with "-" in the first row or the group while in the sortedlist its located in the last row of the group.
this is my code:

```
public partial class Form1: Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    SortedList<object, object> sortedvbcombo = new SortedList<object, object>();
    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Data[] D = new Data[5];
        D[0] = new Data();
        D[0].name = "BABA";
        D[0].number = 1000;
        D[1] = new Data();
        D[1].name = "B-REAL";
        D[1].number = 1001;
        D[2] = new Data();
        D[2].name = "BCCDC";
        D[2].number = 1002;
        D[3] = new Data();
        D[3].name = "BAAAAA";
        D[3].number = 1003;
        D[4] = new Data();
        D[4].name = "BFFFFDS";
        D[4].number = 1004;
        comboBox1.Sorted = true;
        for (int i = 0; i < D.Count(); i++)
        {
            comboBox1.Items.Add(D[i].name);
            sortedvbcombo.Add(D[i].name, D[i].number);
        }

    }
}
struct Data
{
    public string name;
    public int number;
}
```

the result for combo box:
B-REAL
BAAAAA
BABA
BCCDC
BFFFFDS

the result for sortedlist:
BAAAAA
BABA
BCCDC
BFFFFDS
B-REAL
why it's not sorting in the same way and if it is possible to align it from the sortedlist properties?
p.s I know there is some possibility to use

```
sortedlist<object,object> srt = new sortedlist<object,object>(idictionary)
```

but I couldn't find the way to implement it

Comment: the main question is why there is a difference between the sorting of the combo-box to the sorting of the sortedlist and how can we align it

Answer (score 0):

one solution i found for now(even though i think the combobox sort is incorrect) is by encoding the data to the sortlist

```
    for (int i = 0; i < D.Count(); i++)
    {
        comboBox1.Items.Add(D[i].name);
        byte[] encbuff = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(D[i].name);
        sortedvbcombo.Add(Convert.ToBase64String(encbuff), D[i].number);
    }
```

is there smarter way to do it with the sortlist or with the combobox sort?